# how fix spawn open ENOENT

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

```
Error: spawn open ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:506:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn open',
  path: 'open',
  spawnargs: [
    '-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\seman_lutfi_mariani\\application\\views\\template\\home_header.php'
  ]
}
```

I have tried the CSS on my local environment, and it is still working fine according to the template I downloaded. However, after uploading it to Git, the web page does not appear as expected based on the template I downloaded earlier. Even though the links and base URL are correct, the CSS is still working but not in line with the template.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you provided indicates that there was an issue with spawning a child process in your code. Specifically, the error code "ENOENT" indicates that the system was unable to locate the file or program you were trying to execute.

In this case, it seems like you were trying to spawn a child process using the command 'open' with some arguments, as specified in the 'spawnargs' property of the error object.

To fix this error, you should ensure that the "open" command is available on your system's PATH.